# Error while trying to include an object's property in <form:hidden/> having object list in modelAttribute

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jstl, modelattribute

I am working on a spring mvc project. I have a view where I list all objects of type Person. The list is successfully displayed with all attributes. However, as I now need to pass the individual object back to the controller upon selection by the user, I have enclosed my list in form tag so that I could bind it with modelAttribute and send the object back to controller. When I try to include a form:hidden field to bind an attribute, I get the following error:

ERROR o.s.w.s.tags.form.HiddenInputTag - Invalid property 'uid' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property 'uid' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'uid' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property 'uid' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

All setters and getters exist for the Person object and the attributes successfully get displayed if I don't include the form:hidden

Model:

```
public class Person {

Integer id;

String uid;

String fullname;

String firstname;

String lastname;

String fathername;

String email;

String status;  

List<String> environments;

List<String> institutions;

public boolean isNew() {
    return (this.id == null);
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public void setUid(String uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}

public String getFullname() {
    return fullname;
}

public void setFullname(String fullname) {
    this.fullname = fullname;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public String getFathername() {
    return fathername;
}

public void setFathername(String fathername) {
    this.fathername = fathername;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}


public List<String> getEnvironments() {
    return environments;
}

public void setEnvironments(List<String> environments) {
    this.environments = environments;
}
public List<String> getInstitutions() {
    return institutions;
}

public void setInstitutions(List<String> institutions) {
    this.institutions = institutions;
}
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/persons/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String listPersons(@RequestParam("searchString") String searchStr, Model model) {

logger.debug("listPersons()");
userService.initialize();
myPersons = userService.searchPersons(searchStr);
model.addAttribute("persons", myPersons);
return "users/listPersons";
}
```

View (listPersons.jsp)

```
<%@ page session="false"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<jsp:include page="../fragments/header.jsp" />

<body>

<div class="container">

    <c:if test="${not empty msg}">
        <div class="alert alert-${css} alert-dismissible" role="alert">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <strong>${msg}</strong>
        </div>
    </c:if>

    <h1>All Persons</h1>

    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>UID</th>
                <th>Full Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Institutions</th>
                <th>Environments</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    <spring:url value="/persons/cards" var="showPersonCardsUrl" />
    <form:form method="post" action="${showPersonCardsUrl}" modelAttribute="persons">
        <c:forEach var="person" items="${persons}" varStatus="status">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    ${person.id}
                </td>
                <td>${person.uid}</td>
                <form:hidden path="uid" />
                <td>${person.fullname}</td>
                <td>${person.email}</td>
                <td><c:forEach var="institution" items="${person.institutions}" varStatus="loop">
                    ${institution}
                    <c:if test="${not loop.last}">,</c:if>
                    </c:forEach>
                </td>
                <td><c:forEach var="environment" items="${person.environments}" varStatus="loop">
                    ${environment}
                    <c:if test="${not loop.last}">,</c:if>
                    </c:forEach>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <spring:url value="/persons/${person.uid}" var="showPersonUrl" />
                    <spring:url value="/persons/${person.uid}/delete" var="deletePersonUrl" /> 
                    <spring:url value="/persons/${person.uid}/update" var="updatePersonUrl" />
                    <spring:url value="/persons/${person.uid}/cards" var="showPersonCardsUrl" />

                    <button class="btn btn-info" onclick="location.href='${showPersonUrl}'">Query</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='${updatePersonUrl}'">Update</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="this.disabled=true;post('${deletePersonUrl}')">Delete</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Cards</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </form:form>
    </table>

</div>

<jsp:include page="../fragments/footer.jsp" />

</body>
</html>
```

Instead of

```
<form:hidden path="uid" />
```

I have also tried

```
<form:hidden path="persons.person.uid"/>
```

and also this

```
<form:hidden path="users[${status.index}].uid"/>
```

but nothing works. I need to pass the person object back to the controller with its uid so that I can do further processing. What could I be doing wrong in this?

Answer (score 0):

The hidden form tag will try to resolve the path from withing the **`modelAttribute`** in the from tag it's inside, for example, your **`modelAttribute`** is **`persons`**, so the hidden form will try to access `persons.uid`
and if you use **`persons.person.uid`** it will resolve to **persons.persons.person.uid**
and so on.

In your case, I suggest using a regular input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="persons[${status.index}]" value="${person.uid}"/>
```

With this, when the form is submitted it will send an array named persons with uid values inside each.

If you still insist on using **`<form:hidden>`** then you need to revisit how you build your form.

Comment: Okay, thanks, got it. I will try with this regular input